# Copy a range from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from one workbook to another.

The following line works:

```vb
Workbooks(TempBook.Name).Worksheets(sheet_Index).Range("A1:A20").Copy _
  Workbooks(mainWB.Name).Worksheets(sheet_Index).Range("A1")
```

This throws

> Application-defined or object-defined

```vb
Workbooks(TempBook.Name).Worksheets(sheet_Index).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
  Workbooks(mainWB.Name).Worksheets(sheet_Index).Range("A1")
```

Why can I not select a dynamic range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` needs to be qualified with the worksheet and workbook, otherwise it's implicitly on the `ActiveSheet`.
2. `Workbooks(TempBook.Name)` should just be `TempBook`. Similarly for `Workbooks(mainWB.Name)`.
3. Side note: you might consider [using `xlUp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) to find the last row instead of `xlDown`.

```vb
With TempBook.Worksheets(sheet_Index)
    .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
        Destination:=mainWb.Worksheets(sheet_Index).Range("A1")
End With
```

Comment: I know that I am supposed to "avoid comments like ... 'thanks'", but.... thanks. You don't know how happy that just made me. As a follow on, why is .xlup better than xldown?

Comment: @JKRH because you could encounter blank rows in the middle, your `xlDown` would stop there, instead `xlUp` will always get the last row since it's coming from the last row in the sheet to the first it finds from below.